# Scipy find peak function and distance parameter

Tags: python, scipy

I'm struggling with the find peaks function from scipy. I have a dataset of approx 20k points. The x axis is the time in second ranging from 0 sec to 20 sec and the y axis represents pressure measurements going from -2 mb to 5 mb. My signal is a sine, nearly a perfect one except from some vibrations (not noise just a quick fluctuation of the pressure before and/or after the max of the sine). So it means that I have a good estimation of the distance between two maxima. To extract the peaks I'm using `scipy.signal.find_peaks(y, height=0, distance=500, prominence=(0.1, 1))` with height equal to 0 as I want positive peaks, prominence is usefull to remove vibration peaks and distance as far I understand it is usefull to remove local maxima between two sine peaks. Unfortunately, I don't understand why but it seems the distance is not the number of points between two maxima. Indeed, for this first command, the result is `array([ 3928,  5047,  6243, 11451, 11955, 13737, 19300]`. If I set the distance to be equal to 1000, the first maxima should still appears as it is spaced by more than 1000 points from the second one, right ? But in that case, I get the following result `array([11955, 19300]`.

What am I missing ?

Thanks for your help :)

[image: result for distance equal to 500]
[image: result for distance equal to 1000]

EDIT.
FFT code
This code returns an amplitude equal to 1.58 which is obviously not correct as the max value is around 4.2 and min around -2.2.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate the time values
duration = 1.0  # Duration of the signal in seconds
sampling_rate = 1000  # Number of samples per second
t = x
signal = y

# Apply the FFT to the signal
fft_result = np.fft.fft(signal)

#number of samples per second
sampling_rate = 1000

# Calculate the amplitudes of the frequencies
frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(len(t), 1.0 / sampling_rate)
amplitudes = np.abs(fft_result) / len(t)

# Find the index of the main frequency component
main_frequency_index = np.argmax(amplitudes)

# Get the amplitude of the main frequency component
main_frequency_amplitude = amplitudes[main_frequency_index]

# Print the result
print("Amplitude of the main frequency component:", main_frequency_amplitude)

# Plot the signal and its frequency spectrum
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax1.plot(t, signal)
ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax1.set_title('Signal')
ax2.stem(frequencies, amplitudes)
ax2.set_xlabel('Frequency')
ax2.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax2.set_title('Frequency Spectrum')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: More broadly, if you're trying to characterise a periodic signal, peak-finding will probably do a worse job than fourier analysis.

Comment: What specifically do you need to do with the peak positions?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay, how can I attach my data ? I want to extract the amplitude of the sine part of my signal. The problem is that it's not a beautiful sine function so FFT returns weird results. I tried to run the code that I added to my question, without success but I am not an expert in FFT analysis.

Comment: the data can be downloaded here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1riWL9XqhA35Pqx70qBvoe3QPmZ-E6LaFjJJsdaePxVg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic FFT analysis looks like

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

irregular_time, irregular_amplitude = np.loadtxt(
    fname='Data - Feuille 1.csv',
    delimiter=',',
).T

time = np.linspace(
    start=irregular_time.min(),
    stop=irregular_time.max(),
    num=irregular_time.size,
)
timestep = time[1] - time[0]
amplitude = np.interp(
    x=time,
    xp=irregular_time,
    fp=irregular_amplitude,
)

spectrum = np.fft.rfft(amplitude, norm='forward')
spectral_amplitude = np.abs(spectrum)
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=time.size, d=timestep)

peak_index = spectral_amplitude.argmax()
peak_freq = freqs[peak_index]
peak_amplitude = 2*spectral_amplitude[peak_index]
peak_phase = np.angle(spectrum[peak_index])

print('Amplitude:', peak_amplitude)
print('Frequency (approx, Hz):', peak_freq)
print('Phase (deg):', np.rad2deg(peak_phase))

reconstructed = peak_amplitude * np.cos(
    2*np.pi*peak_freq*time + peak_phase
) + np.abs(spectrum[0])

ax_top: plt.Axes
ax_bottom: plt.Axes
fig, (ax_top, ax_bottom) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

ax_top.plot(time, amplitude, label='experiment')
ax_top.plot(time, reconstructed, label='reconstructed')
ax_top.set_xlabel('Interpolated time (s)')
ax_top.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax_top.legend(loc='lower right')

ax_bottom.semilogx(freqs, spectral_amplitude)
ax_bottom.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ax_bottom.set_ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.show()
```

```
Amplitude: 3.183337345334171
Frequency (approx, Hz): 0.1499400170118757
Phase (deg): 86.4919931694836
```

[image: fit]

The frequency is only approximate because it's fairly low given the low number of cycles in your sample, and the bins do not initially align with your peak. This will be improved with spectral peak estimation and a longer sample. You've provided the longer sample; the spectral peak estimation is courtesy Jacobsen's parabolic interpolator:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

irregular_time, irregular_amplitude = np.loadtxt(
    fname='Data - Feuille 1.csv',
    delimiter=',',
).T

time = np.linspace(
    start=irregular_time.min(),
    stop=irregular_time.max(),
    num=irregular_time.size,
)
timestep = time[1] - time[0]
amplitude = np.interp(
    x=time,
    xp=irregular_time,
    fp=irregular_amplitude,
)

# first pass
spectrum = np.fft.rfft(amplitude, norm='forward')
spectral_amplitude = np.abs(spectrum)
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=time.size, d=timestep)
peak_index = spectral_amplitude.argmax()

# Instead of peak_freq = freqs[peak_index]
# use parabolic peak interpolation from http://www.ericjacobsen.org/fe2/quadterp.txt
a, b, c = spectrum[peak_index-1: peak_index+2]
norm_frac = np.real((a - c)/(2*b - a - c))
peak_freq_interpolated = freqs[peak_index]*(1 + norm_frac) - freqs[peak_index - 1]*norm_frac

# second pass
# shorten the timeseries length so that the peak lands in the next-left bin
excerpt = int(np.round(time.size * freqs[peak_index-1] / peak_freq_interpolated))
spectrum = np.fft.rfft(amplitude[:excerpt], norm='forward')
spectral_amplitude = np.abs(spectrum)
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=excerpt, d=timestep)
peak_index = spectral_amplitude.argmax()
peak_freq = freqs[peak_index]
peak_phase = np.angle(spectrum[peak_index])
peak_amplitude = 2*spectral_amplitude[peak_index]

print('Amplitude:', peak_amplitude)
print('Frequency (approx, Hz):', peak_freq)
print('Phase (deg):', np.rad2deg(peak_phase))

reconstructed = peak_amplitude * np.cos(
    2*np.pi*peak_freq*time + peak_phase
) #+ spectral_amplitude[0]  # optional DC offset

ax_top: plt.Axes
ax_bottom: plt.Axes
fig, (ax_top, ax_bottom) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

ax_top.plot(time, amplitude, label='experiment')
ax_top.plot(time, reconstructed, label='reconstructed')
ax_top.set_xlabel('Interpolated time (s)')
ax_top.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax_top.legend(loc='lower right')

ax_bottom.semilogx(freqs, spectral_amplitude)
ax_bottom.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ax_bottom.set_ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.show()
```

[image: interpolated]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I extracted more data an uploaded on the previous google sheet. When I directly use the FFT on it we can see that this technique doesn't work anymore as the vibration contribution is more important. I'm looking for ideas to fine tune this solution in order to make it work for every set of data I have. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: "every set of data I have" is too broad and no one algorithm can handle arbitrary data. If you have a dataset where there's a higher-frequency component that you need to be ignored, manually set a search threshold frequency when looking for spectral peaks.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and example. I will try to combine that with my current technique wich is removing every contribution from high frequencies as my target frequency is very low and vibrations have high ones